# Bootstrap DateTimePicker issue selecting maxDate when input has no value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Using the Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker v4 http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ along with Moment 2.9 and the other required files.

I'm needing to trigger a change event when a user selects a date with the picker, regardless of the value of the input field. It made sense to me to have an empty value for the input and instead use a placeholder with the maximum allowed value.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group date" id="dayjump">
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="24" name="dayportal" id="dayportal" />
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
</div></div>
</div>
```

Issue that I seem to be having is the maxDate cannot be selected when the input has no value. Presence of a placeholder seems to make no difference in the issue.

```
$("#dayjump").datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    format: "D",
    minDate: moment("2/7/2015","M/D/YYYY"),
    maxDate: moment("02/24/2015","M/D/YYYY"),
    icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
        down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
        previous: "fa fa-angle-left",
        next: "fa fa-angle-right",
        today: "fa fa-thumb-tack",
        clear: "fa fa-trash"
    }
});
$("#dayjump").on("dp.change",function (e) {
    var y = moment(e.date).format("YYYY");
    _m = moment(e.date).format("M");
    _d = moment(e.date).format("D");
    alert("year=" + y + " month=" + _m + " date=" + _d);
});
```

see fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/spasticdonkey/waoLzwz5/1/

you will notice in the example that all dates except the maxDate can be selected, and attempting to select the maxDate will not update the input field as well.

Comment: could you be more clear mate..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, it's bug. I have warning in console:

*Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.*

You can use crutch to fix this:

```
maxDate: moment("02/25/2015","M/D/YYYY"),
disabledDates: [
      "02/25/2015"
],
```

Set the date +1 and disable it.

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/maxlipsky/waoLzwz5/4/

Comment: thanks for your time and your suggestion could be a possible solution for me, although my actual form is a little more complicated and has month and year selection pickers; which are producing a different error. `TypeError: o.find is not a function` [link](http://jsfiddle.net/spasticdonkey/bfw9zm3c/1/)

Comment: you are correct, it was a bug and looks to have already been addressed in their development branch.

Comment: a year after this, has this bug been fixed?

Answer (score 2):

The way I fixed this is to set `maxDate` as follows:

```
maxDate: new Date().setHours(23,59,59,999)
```

If you set maxDate to `new Date()` only, then it won't allow today's date to be selected as the maximum date selectable has passed by the time the page has rendered.

Comment: This should be the correct answer because if you try the accepted answer then you can't select the next date but you can type that next date.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
maxDate: moment("02/24/2015 23:59:59","MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
```

We don't explicitly need to mention and disable the date like the accepted answer

```
maxDate: moment("02/25/2015","M/D/YYYY") 
disabledDates: [ "02/25/2015" ]
```

Rather I feel this is a better fix.Please find the js fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/AbhinayKumarGunna/6jx723ep/57](http://jsfiddle.net/AbhinayKumarGunna/6jx723ep/57)

Comment: Please try to elaborate why this worked for you. There is almost no difference between what is already in the code that is in question. Why does adding time to the date make a difference. Please post a working example if you can.

Comment: @mcphersonjr We don't explicitly need to mention and disable the date like above maxDate: moment("02/25/2015","M/D/YYYY"), disabledDates: [ "02/25/2015" ], Rather I feel this is a better fix.Please find the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AbhinayKumarGunna/6jx723ep/57/

Comment: I added your comments to the answer. Please edit as you wish and update it with a Bootstrap version, as that will be helpful in the future.